# Расчёт ОЗУ сервера для запуска нескольких докер-контейнеров

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, docker

Я хочу поднять сервер на базе скажем centos7/debian10, установить на нём докер и держать запущенными несколько (допустим, пять-десять) моих приложений, завёрнутых в контейнер.

Каким образом мне рассчитать необходимое количество ОЗУ на сервере, чтобы приложения нормально работали? Как можно узнать, что пора увеличивать объём памяти / переходить на другой тариф, какие параметры необходимо мониторить и на какие диапазоны ориентироваться?

Для определённости: приложения будут однотипные (это как-то уменьшает количество потребляемых ресурсов или докер даже на одинаковые контейнеры будет честно выделять копии ресурсов, дублируя их или как-то учитывать, что это тот же самый ресурс и можно держать одну копию на все контейнеры?) [приложения asp.net core 2.2](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/samples/aspnetapp) + один контейнер будет nginx.

Comment: Не проще ли провести динамический анализ Ваших приложений и для каждого контейнера указать необходимое кол-во ресурсов? а потом просто посчитаете.

Comment: @Beeen007 В вопросе есть про это: какие параметры мониторить, в каких диапазонах должны быть значения. И всё-таки хотелось бы хоть какой-то ориентир для начала. Условно: хватит ли 1 Гб ОЗУ, чтобы стартовать с двумя-тремя контейнерами или нужно не менее двух брать? (четырёх, восьми...) И если на одном гигабайте оно взлетит -- как понять, что пришла пора второй добавлять?

Comment: Опять вопрос. Откуда мы можем знать что ваш код не аллоцирует все 4гб виртуальной памяти ? На мой взгляд только динамический анализ

Comment: Мониторить потребление ресурса от начала форка пида до момента максимальной нагрузки

Comment: @Beeen007 Основную мысль я понял. Но если какой-то методики расчёта нет, то может у вас есть какие-то конкретные рекомендации привести на тему что конкретно за параметры мониторить и в каких диапазонах они должны находиться?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/tank/ - наверное можно этим побомбить прогу и посмотреть как она пожрёт ресурсы.

Comment: Мне не удалось найти инструмента, замеряющего мгновенные всплески потребления памяти процессов и пригодного для продакшена. Если я не слепой и такого правда нет, то боюсь, что задача принципиально нерешаемая, а всё предложенное в комментариях выше и в ответе ниже рискует являться очень грубыми оценками, далёкими от реальности

Comment: `Мне не удалось найти инструмента...` - нужно встраивать метрики в приложение, считать самостоятельно именно то, что интересует.

Comment: @Sheridan вы почему-то старательно игнорируете то, что приложение может быть чужим и/или без исходных кодов

Comment: > `...установить на нём докер и держать запущенными несколько (допустим, пять-десять) моих приложений...`

Comment: @Sheridan в по-настоящему своих приложениях пики так-то обычно изначально известны и в метриках вообще нет нужды; вы как-то| слишком узко мыслите и почему-то упорно отказываетесь рассмотреть проблему более широко

Comment: О, загуглив более хитро, я таки нашёл нужную метрику `VmHWM` в `/proc/[pid]/status` (ну и кому пришло в голову приплести сюда уровень воды, чтобы я не cмог эту метрику найти?), она же `ru_maxrss`в `getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF)`, так что отбой тревоги, инструмент есть.)

Comment: Интересная статья, которая поможет в мониторинге нагрузки https://unixism.net/2019/08/linux-pressure-stall-information-psi-by-example/

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно развернуть проект на просторном стенде, настроить мониторинг и нагрузить полезной нагрузкой на какое-то время. По результатам будет понятно что следует ожидать.

Самый удобный, на мой взгляд, стек мониторинга это [prometheus](https://prometheus.io)+[node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter)/[telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/)+[grafana](https://grafana.com/). Метрик по умолчанию, думаю вам хватит для анализа. Плюс к тому, вы можете встроить метрики и в свои приложения при желании.

К полученным результатам желательно добавить ~10% сверху. Чтобы было время для манёвра если нагрузка превысит ожидаемую.

Comment: Что если проект в один момент забирает много гигов памяти и тут же (менее чем через секунду) её освобождает? Поймает ли это предложенный стек?

Comment: Много гигов в секунду туда-обратно? really? Если так, то вам нужны встроенные в приложение метрики.

Comment: А если разработчики говнокодеры и не потрудились прикрутить метрики или упомянуть потребление памяти в документации - как мне как админу узнать об их существовании, кроме как от OOM Killer'a на продакшене?)

Comment: Обложить метриками с нужным периодом? Дополнить метрики своими экспортерами? Сидеть сложа руки? Я теряюсь в вариантах... :))

Comment: Достаточно малый период начнёт жрать уже процессор и всё равно рискует пропустить очень быстрый пик, так что это сомнительный вариант

Comment: Тем не менее, нужны метрики. Если вам будет удобно - да хоть в лог. Но лично я предпочту вышеописанный стек плюс придумать воркараунд для пиков по памяти. И в любом случае встроить метрики в само приложение.